# How Do E-Commerce Websites Calculate Postage/Shipping Costs?

Tags: e-commerce

I'm just wondering if anyone can provide me with some information into how e-commerce websites automatically calculate the postage and shipping costs for items ordered on-line?

Do these websites use plug-ins/web services to dynamically request this information from the postage/shipping provider? Or do developers manually retrieve the postage costs from the associated shipping provider and then develop their own approximate postage/shipping cost calculation algorithm (in agreement with the e-commerce business of course)? Or are there any alternative approaches used?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I have done some basic research on the topic. I've seen some plug-ins for WordPress but each plug-in was limited to specific postage/shipping companies only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do these websites use plug-ins/web services to dynamically request
>   this information from the postage/shipping provider?

Yes, this is certainly an option. In my experience, the APIs provided by [UPS](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit) and [FedEx](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer) are decent and work for the UK market.

> Or do developers manually retrieve the postage costs from the
>   associated shipping provider and then develop their own approximate
>   postage/shipping cost calculation algorithm?

I would not recommend this - a maintenance headache for one reason - and have never seen it done.

> Or are there any alternative approaches used?

Sometimes, fixed shipping-costs can be used - for example, when delivery is to a single country or products weights are relatively static. No API call is needed in these scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my research, I've found that there doesn't seem to be a single standardised way of calculating shipping/postage costs on e-commerce websites. Some companies provide plugins for WordPress, etcetera, to assist in this process, while others companies provide API's.

Primarily, I'm interested in using a UK based shipping/postage provider.

The Royal Mail is the largest postal provider in the UK and it provides an [API](http://www.royalmail.com/parcel-despatch-medium/uk-delivery/parcel-shipping-solutions/shipping-api) for a number of tasks; however no official API appears to be available for cost calculation. I did however manage to find an unofficial Royal Mail cost calculation API. It can be found at the following [link](http://royalmail-api.hook.im/).